# Appending children

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I hate my life. I'm trying to complete a simple tutorial that takes an empty div and adds a bunch of cat images to it. The details of the cats are contained within arrays, which are applied to each instance of a cat while iterating through a simple numeric array.

At the bottom of the script, you'll see that I'm alerting the innerHTML of the main container div which all of these images and header tags are supposed to be appended to. While the alert dialogue shows the correct HTML, the divs that are being generated lack the img and h1 elements, despite my attempts to get them to append properly. All that seems to be getting passed through are the h1 text nodes.

Can anyone please explain why I'm not getting the results I'm looking for here:

```js
    var cats_array = [1,2,3,4,5];

    var cats_names = ['Jim','Joe','Jon','Larry','Mike'];

    var cats_urls = [
      'https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-senior-landing-hero.ashx',
      'http://i2.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article6745691.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Black-cat.jpg',
      'https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-breed-landing-hero.ashx',
      'https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Subpage-Hero-Images/150327_Hero_kit.ashx',
      'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/a7/92/d8/a792d8ec74bbcc819bb65c7bad1f8dee.jpg'
    ];

    for (cat in cats_array) {

      var catgame_div = document.getElementById('catgame');
      var num_div = document.createElement('DIV');
      var img_el = document.createElement('IMG');
      var h1_el = document.createElement('H1');
      
      var current_cats_name = cats_names[cat];
      var h1_text_node = document.createTextNode(current_cats_name);

      h1_el.appendChild(h1_text_node);
      img_el.src = cats_urls[cat];
      num_div.appendChild(img_el);

      var img_parent = img_el.parentNode;

      img_parent.insertBefore(h1_el, img_el);

      alert(img_parent.innerHTML);

      catgame_div.appendChild(num_div);

    }
```

```html
<div id="catgame"></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: [Works fine for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/yxd0sfhh/1/) Perhaps you're not loading your code at the right time. Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log)

Comment: Putting your code in jsfiddle it works as you are wanting however the URLs that are handlers (ASHX) do not return images and are not valid URLs

Comment: @Kyle [Yes there are.](https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-breed-landing-hero.ashx)

Comment: Weird, I was just setting up a JS Fiddle and it worked.

Comment: First one: https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Product-Categories/cat-senior-landing-hero.ashx I get site cannot be reached.

Comment: @Kyle That's weird. Works just fine for me. Must be something wrong on your or your providers end.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Yes could be our firewall, but either way the code it running correctly for me. We would need to see more of your code, always a good idea to setup a jsfiddle so we can properly diagnose your issue.